# How can I make a minimal installation with autoinstall?

Tags: 20.04

I'm trying to build a custom Ubuntu image with [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) using the Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS AMD64 iso image. How do I have to configure `user-data` that a minimal installation is executed?

Answer (score 1):

As evidenced by comparing `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` between autoinstalled and manually installed 22.04 servers, there is no such selection exposed. It seems to be an installer internal option.

The installed size is still 2.3GB compared to the normal 2.7GB, so 'minimal' is relative. For example, `snap` is still present on minimal, but `less` has been removed, so it is by no means just the necessary packages.

It is worth remembering that the kernel and related bits take up ~1.5GB. The minimal option does make a big difference on containers and VM's with tiny kernels.

Comment: yes, snap should not be at minimal installation... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Old post but its the first one that comes up when googling asking how to do a minimal install with autoinstall (user-data). So I will post it here.

And I think I found out how it can be done. Tested with 22.04 LTS. Tested how? Full install installs 'nano' Minimal does not. Heck minimal does not even have 'ping'. Yeah not very scientific but good enough for me.

```
autoinstall:
  source:
    id: ubuntu-server-minimal
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not an answer (please reply if you found one), but an ugly workaround is to use a late-command in the autoinstall user-data to remove as much as you can afterwards to minify after the install. There doesnt seem to be anything in the docs, and there's only one reference in the source, in an example file that I can't decipher: https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/206b7ae678bc1993e1eef46c74efb12f30dbbb43/examples/install-sources.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this.

user-data:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  instance-id: iid-auto-default
  version: 1
  refresh-installer:
    update: yes
    channel: edge
  early-commands:
    - ping -c1 8.8.8.8
    - ip -br -4  -c addr show | head -n 3
    - systemctl stop ssh # otherwise packer tries to connect and exceed max attempt
  apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
      - arches:
          - amd64
        uri: 'http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu'
      - arches:
          - default
        uri: 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports'
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu
    password: >-
      $6$h.zoLndLImptklKU$RQVTwlPvXno7Zw0f1NpTkoRemOZckpHx3TkMZDc5hC5pZJQoDFwUZPsJnm5bbhxTqmhwu6oDuP.bLH0qDtXON/
    realname: ubuntu
    username: ubuntu
  user-data:
    disable_root: false
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  locale: en_US
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []      
    install-server: false
  packages:
    - ubuntu-desktop-minimal #if you want desktop UI
  late-commands:
    - cp /cdrom/nocloud/post_install.sh /target/opt/
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- /opt/post_install.sh
  updates: security
  storage: 
    config: 
      - id: disk-sda
        type: disk
        ptable: gpt
        match:
          size: largest
        wipe: superblock
        preserve: false
        name: ''
        grub_device: false
      - id: partition-0
        type: partition
        device: disk-sda
        size: 512M
        wipe: superblock
        flag: boot
        number: 1
        preserve: false
        grub_device: true
      - id: format-0
        type: format
        fstype: fat32
        volume: partition-0
        preserve: false
      - id: partition-1
        type: partition
        device: disk-sda
        size: 1G
        wipe: superblock
        flag: ''
        number: 2
        preserve: false
        grub_device: false
      - id: format-1
        type: format
        fstype: ext4
        volume: partition-1
        preserve: false
      - id: partition-2
        type: partition
        device: disk-sda
        size: -1
        wipe: superblock
        flag: ''
        number: 3
        preserve: false
        grub_device: false
      - id: dm_crypt-0
        type: dm_crypt
        volume: partition-2
        key: ThisIsASecretKey
        preserve: false
      - id: lvm_volgroup-0
        type: lvm_volgroup
        name: ubuntu-vg
        devices:
          - dm_crypt-0
        preserve: false
      - id: lvm_partition-0
        type: lvm_partition
        name: ubuntu-lv
        volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
        size: -1
        preserve: false
      - id: format-2
        type: format
        fstype: ext4
        volume: lvm_partition-0
        preserve: false
      - id: mount-2
        type: mount
        device: format-2
        path: /
      - id: mount-1
        type: mount
        device: format-1
        path: /boot
      - id: mount-0
        type: mount
        device: format-0
        path: /boot/efi
  system_upgrade:
    enabled: False
  error-commands:
    - tail -n 500 /var/log/syslog | grep -E 'subiquity/Error' -B 100
```

fyi: I'm currently developing a universal user-data with several different profiles/variations.
Right now I'm struggling with persistent environment vars and late-command

Answer (score 0):

here is a example of my  late commands. i just made  the extended config when first boot after install with the payloaded post_install.sh, which for sure delete the line in rc.local after run. the folder /addfiles where before added to the iso.

late-commands:
- echo 'admin* ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/admin
- cp /cdrom/server/addfiles/post-install.sh  /target/root/
- cp /cdrom/server/addfiles/z.tar  /target/root/
- curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod +x /root/post-install.sh
- curtin in-target --target=/target -- echo -e "#!/bin/bash -e\n/bin/bash /root/post-install.sh\nexit 0" > /target/etc/rc.local
- curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod 700 /etc/rc.local